# determine a pop up value by using file_get_contents

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value of javascript pop-up after using `file_get_contents`.

```
<?php

$word = 'delete';
$page_content = file_get_contents($url);

if(strstr($page_content, $word)):
$result = 'YES';
else:
$result = 'NO';
endif;

?>
```

my code detect if there is sepecific word in the page. However, it fails to get value on javascript pop-up.

Let's assume that there is a website which has a javascript pop-up.

`file_get_contents($the_website_url)` will only get html data of the website.

I am trying to get javascript pop-up value too by using php script.

Is there a way to get javascript value of external web page?

Comment: Your question in unclear, please rephrase. What has PHP got to do with JS popup?

Comment: can you define `javascript pop-up` or the string your looking for

Comment: @Thrustmaster I added more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is complicated at best, impossible otherwise.

If the popup is being generated from an external javascript resource, you may be able to parse the contents of loading the URL and load the javascript files that it references, checking each of them.

It is possible, however, that the text is either from the user, or from a dynamic load after the fact, which would make it prohibitively difficult for you to parse out.

Comment: yeah.. I know that it only get html value. just want to know that if I can get javascript value of the external web page.

Comment: If the value you are hoping to find is included in the html output (as inline javascript or other representation), then it is possible. But the nature of HTML documents is that they have a dynamic execution environment (the browser), and in order for a server script to "see" everything a user sees (esp. where javascript is involved) may involve complicated browser simulation, and will be shoddy at best.